# Evaluate $ \int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log(\theta)}} ~d\theta $ in polar coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

The objective is to:

> Evaluate $$ \int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log(\theta)}} ~d\theta $$ in polar coordinates.

---

Using cartesian coordinates:

The integral, where $K$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}} \, dx =2K_1(2), $$

Can be evaluated using the substitution $x = e^{-1/\xi},$ which gives the Mellin transform of $e^{-\xi - 1/\xi}:$

$$\mathcal M[e^{-\xi - 1/\xi}] = 2 K_{-s}(2), \\
\int_0^1 e^{1 / \ln x} dx =
\mathcal M[e^{-\xi - 1/\xi}](-1).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}  e^{1/\ln \theta} d\theta$$
Let $1/\ln theta=x$ then
$$I=-\int_{0}^{-\infty} e^{x+1/x}~ \frac{1}{x^2} dx= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(y+1/y)} \frac{1}{y^2} dy$$
Let $y=e^{u}$ then
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u} e^{-(e^u+e^{-u})} du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\cosh u -\sinh u) e^{-2\cosh u} du$$ $$\implies I=2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \cosh u~ e^{-2\cosh u} du$$
We have used the evenness and oddness of the integrand.
Using the standard defibition of cylinderical modifies Bessel function of second kinf ($K_{\nu}(z))$ we get
$$I=2 K_1(2)$$
See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: the integral gives the same result in polar and cartesian coordinates?

Comment: It is simple integral of one dimendion, Here $\theta$ can be angle, length, ehergy,.. any fhing.

Comment: @geocal33 the question of radial, angular or cartesian   arises in two or more dimensions.You may write it as $\int_{0}^{1} \exp(1/\alpha)~d\alpha$ it is all the same because it not double/triple integral.